# How to access AC Flow Sensor on a 2011 Lexus R350

Tags: toyota, ac, sensor, lexus, lexus-rx

How can I access the AC Flow Sensor on a 2011 Lexus RX350? I opened the hood, remove the plastic covers, can't find it.

Do I need to go under the car to get access to it?

Answer (score 1):

Before you replace the sensor, read my note at the end.

The flow sensor is on the A/C compressor itself:

[image: e]

More detail here:

[image: e]

NOTE: These images are from ClubLexus.com, where there is a long post that describes fixing the sensor without replacing it. It involves sticking a rare earth magnet to the C-clip that retains the sensor. Suggest you check it out before replacing the sensor. The link takes you mid-way into the 12-page article, so you might want to page back to read it from the beginning.

[Photo credit and link to article](https://www.clublexus.com/forums/rx-3rd-gen-2010-2015/824215-rx350-2010-2011-air-conditioning-dtc-b1479-cheap-solution-8.html).

Comment: Excellent post ... +1